# How to split the screen in more then one part

Tags: java, android, stream

I am trying to implement an app that plays RTMP url which I have done already using libvlc sdk.

Now I want to split the screen more than one part and want to play rtmp url I am facing problem with spliting the screen any suggestions will be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To Split Android activity  , You should use fragment class which allows you to show multiple task dynamically. You can use fragment class .

**Steps :**
  1. Create Fragment class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class yourFragmentName extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

2. Create FrameLayout in your activity where you want to show fragment.

   `<FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </FrameLayout>`
3. In your Main Activity , add this layout to fragment

   `FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   // Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
   ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
   // or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
   // Complete the changes added above
   ft.commit();`
4. For the second fragment also repeat same.

For more explanation  refer , https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Answer (score 0):

With the help of fragments you can slit the screen into multiple part and each one will have its own UI